# MainWindow object has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python-3.x, signals-slots, pyqt5

I wonder if someone could help me resolve this issue regarding slot connection in PyQt5. The following code snippet will show you what my problem is.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'GUI/Main_GUI.ui')
        self.gui = loadUi(path)

        self.gui.button_1.clicked.connect(self.run.this)

    def _connect_my_slots(self, origin):
        self.connect(origin, SIGNAL('completed'), self._show_results)
        self.connect(origin, SIGNAL('error'), self._show_error)

    def run_this(self):
        myThread = LongRunningThing()
        self._connect_my_slots(self.myThread) # THIS IS THE PART THAT CAUSES ERROR
```

As you can see my `MainWindow` object is my UI file (from QtDesigner 5) and once I call `_connect_my_slots` function it throws an error:

> AttributError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'connect'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the old style signal and slot, which is not longer supported in PyQt5.

The old style:

```
self.connect(origin, SIGNAL('completed'), self._show_results)
```

should now be written in the new style:

```
origin.completed.connect(self._show_results)
```

For more details, see the documentation on [New-style Signal and Slot Support](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot tmoreau old-style signals were the cause of problem. Just to make sure that I'm on the right track, could you please tell me if my EMIT statement is also an old style:

self.emit(SIGNAL('completed'), self.result)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it's old style. "SIGNAL" is your clue. Everything you need to know on signals is on the linked documentation page (even is it's for PyQt4, it should work the same)

Comment: Thanks again tmoreau. I'm already going through that document. Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: tmoreau can you please take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528823/retrieving-information-from-dictionary-pyqt5-and-python-3-4). Maybe you can help me once more ;)