# Retrieving information from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm having hard time trying to read my dictionary variable. Python keeps throwing the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

This is a sample that should give you an idea of what my problem is:

```
self.dict = {}
self.dict['User'] = 'User_name'
self.dict['Dir'] = 'user_home_dir'
self.dict['userID'] = 1

if self.dict['userID'] == 1:    # this is the line that is said to contain an error
    then do somethin ...
```

This is all I get as a Traceback:

```
user_id = self.dict['userID']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

No I'm positive that `self.dict` is not a string.

It's being created in a function called createUser and it's being returned to the main thread.

```
def createUser(self):
    self.dict = {}

    ... user inputs information ...
    ... and then information is inserted into self.dict ...

    self.dict['User'] = self.lineEdit_User.text()
    self.dict['Dir'] = self.lineEdit_path.text()
    self.dict['userID'] = int(self.lineEdit_ID.text())

    return self.dict
```

After that `self.dict` is only referenced for reading data from it.

Comment: You have `self.dict = {}` then you use `dict`, there is also nothing in what you have provided that would cause your error

Comment: Sorry for that, it was a typo. I've edited the example code to represent more accurately my problem. I've been experimenting and it seems like the interpreter doesn't see 'userID' as a number. That's why I'm getting this error message. However I can't see a way to fix that.

Comment: Your error suggests you are doing something like `"foo"["abc"]` not looking up a dict, add the full traceback.

Comment: I've added a full traceback. Maybe I should mention that I'm setting the 'userID' value in the self.dict inside a thread. I don't think that should be a problem.

Comment: `self.dict` is a str not a dict, you have reassigned the name somewhere if it did once point to a dict

Comment: Thanks Padraic. I'll look more and try to find an error.

Comment: Look for a line like `self.dict = `; that's likely the problem.

Comment: The question still has the typo `if dict` instead of `if self.dict`.  Fix that with a note `EDIT: changed 'dict' to 'self.dict' as per first comment`.  Then try to produce an mcve that has the problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  I suspect you will find the cause in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem, and it was in my signal definition. Dictionary 'self.dict' is being returned via pyqtSignal which was defined like this:

```
addUser = pyqtSignal(object)
```

After thorough examination of my code I've figured out that I should change it to:

```
addUser = pyqtSignal(dict)
```

and once I did that it was all right. Once again, thanks everyone for their contribution.